# Is Galaxy Nexus a small, normal, large or x-large device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing a multiscreen Android 2.2.2 application.

To test different screens sizes I'm using **eclipse** (Juno release) **graphic layout**. This is what I have.

**main_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/no_conectado" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelSelGateName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/labelSelGateName_marginTop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labelSelGateName_textsize" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelSelOpened"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labelSelGateName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/labelSelOpened_marginTop"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/labelSelOpened_textsize" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/indicatorActivityView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/indicatorActivityView_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/indicatorActivityView_width"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labelSelOpened"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/indicatorActivityView_marginTop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnMyGates"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnMyGates_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnMyGates_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/indicatorActivityView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/btnMyGates_marginLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btnMyGates_marginTop"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onGateClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnOpen_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnOpen_height"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnMyGates"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onOpenDoorClick" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnClose_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnClose_height"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnMyGates"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btnClose_marginBottom"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onCloseDoorClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnOptions"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnOptions_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnOptions_height"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnMyGates"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnOptions_marginRight"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onOptionClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFaqs"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnFaqs_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnFaqs_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btnFaqs_marginTop"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnOptions"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnClose"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onFAQClick" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnInfo_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnInfo_height"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnOptions"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/btnInfo_marginLeft"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/layout_empty"
        android:onClick="onInfoClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="labelSelGateName_marginTop">40dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="labelSelGateName_textsize">14sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="labelSelOpened_marginTop">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="labelSelOpened_textsize">14sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="indicatorActivityView_width">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="indicatorActivityView_height">20dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="indicatorActivityView_marginTop">28dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnMyGates_width">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnMyGates_height">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnMyGates_marginLeft">29dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnMyGates_marginTop">60dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnOpen_width">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnOpen_height">55dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnClose_width">90dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnClose_height">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnClose_marginBottom">0dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnOptions_width">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnOptions_height">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnOptions_marginRight">30dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnFaqs_width">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnFaqs_height">70dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnFaqs_marginTop">10dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="btnInfo_width">110dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnInfo_height">60dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="btnInfo_marginLeft">14dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I have four `dimens.xml` in these folders: `values-small`, `values-normal`, `values-large` and `values-xlarge`.

With these files it looks good in `Nexus One`, `7in WSVGA Tablet` and `10.1in WXGA Tablet`. However, it doesn't look good in `Galaxy Nexus`, `5.4 FWVGA`, `5.1 WVGA` and `4.7in WXGA`.

When I say it doesn't look good I mean that every `TextView`, `ImageButton`, etc. has moved and they aren't in their right place.

Do I need more files?

Comment: What SDK version are you targetting?

Comment: @AlexLockwood android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a limitation of Android initial design - its XML layout does not allow to specify percent-based or table-like layouts similar to HTML tables, i.e. layout without exact dimensions.

"weight" attribute is not an option because when I try to specify arbitrary layout, Eclipse tells me that "Nested weights are bad for performance"

Qualifiers are not a good architect solution as well because two different devices may be qualified under the same "screen-density" pair, for example HTC One S / HTC One X. That's why Google re-designed it introducing swdp qualifiers in 3.x.

For the Android 2.3 you may create a "default" UI optimized for 480x800 and layout it in the screen center. It will look smaller on 540x960 and higher screens, but still uncorrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy Nexus has a `normal` screen (its resolution being `1280 x 720`) and has `xhdpi` density.

Comment: I'm testing it with eclipse graphics layout and it doesn't look good. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: I have a Galaxy Nexus... if you feel comfortable you could [**email**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/p/contact.html) me the `.apk` and I could send you a screenshot of what it looks like. It could very well be a bug with eclipse, but you probably should test it on a real device just to be sure. (I won't judge, I promise :P).

Comment: I have asked this question about `Galaxy Nexus`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779002/how-to-set-up-layout-to-galaxy-nexus

Answer (score 0):

galaxy nexus (and galaxy s3 , and htc one x) has a normal screen size , with xhdpi density.

reference:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=PwC1OlJo5VM#t=3047s

Comment: I'm testing it with eclipse graphics layout and it doesn't look good. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: don't count on the visual editor of eclipse . it's usually ok , but  sometimes it can give wrong results . better trust emulators , and of course real devices.

Comment: I have asked this question about `Galaxy Nexus`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779002/how-to-set-up-layout-to-galaxy-nexus

Comment: this question is about the galaxy nexus. the other link you've published is about a problem that is not related to galaxy nexus at all . anyway , i've answered there too.

Comment: The other question is related to Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: no , it was a general question related to putting views in correct position and size , no matter what is the device . the current question is about galaxy nexus - which screen it has.